# 4mm hex shank to 1/4" hex shank adapter

Tags: product-recommendation, screwdriver, bits

I have a screwdriver which uses interchangeable bits and a magnet to hold them in place. The screwdriver takes 4mm hex shank sized bits. It seems this shank size is really rare, because I can't find any security bits with a shank of this size. Everywhere I look I see 1/4" hex shanks. So, I am wondering if there is an adapter that exists which converts 1/4" hex shanks down to a 4mm size so they can fit my screwdriver. I have seen a number of products which do the opposite, allowing screwdrivers/drills which take 1/4" shanks to use bits with 4mm shanks, but I haven't found any adapters which *upscale* the shank size I can use.

The closest thing I can find to what I am looking for is [this product](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B004W7H6NQ), but it adapts a 4mm hex shank to a larger *square* socket

Why is this? Where can I find an adapter that I need? I would actually prefer to just find a pack of security bits which use 4mm hex shanks so I don't need an adapter, but I don't think they exist.

Comment: Did you search with term micro or mini hex as a term? That is the more common name for 4mm drive bits. Also, do you know what T size you need for your security bits?

Comment: Might be easier to go the other way and find yourself a 1/4 drive magnetic screwdriver and buy something like this https://www.kctoolco.com/wiha-75802-1-4-insert-bit-to-system-4-micro-bit-adaptor-magnetic/ to allow your 1/4" drivers to accept 4mm bits

Comment: Oh and one last clarification, you do mean TORX security bits when you say security bits. right?

Comment: Sorry for the late response. My purpose for buying security bits is so I can open up my SCUF controller, and specifically I know that I can use a spanner bit for this. Though, I would like to just buy a set of security bits so I can use them for other things in the future if I need them (so Torx, Star, Tri Wing, etc is all within scope). Unfortunately the term "mini hex" doesn't seem to be bringing up any useful results. I was hoping to use my current screwdriver because it's actually pretty nice with a ratchet and stuff, but I may just have to buy one that takes 1/4" bits...